# How can I argue the year range for a sample?

Tags: sampling

I’m writing a thesis about alexythimic levels based on emo-stroop test results.

What could be a good age rate sample? What would be the reason to say I will exclude subjects younger and older than X? Is it easily argued with some already published works? I have read similar works and no one are giving reasons about their selected age range.

Comment: as in, "subjects younger than x and older than y years were excluded?" also: honours thesis or postgrad?

Comment: @faustus Sorry, I meant, what could be a good reason to say I will exclude younger and older ranges?

Comment: dude, you're not doing a thesis. even honours level you should get it. if you are, then i will help if you show that you're thinking about it. (BTW i know nothing about this area -- you should be able to work it out from first principles). ask yourself what happens to your statistical analysis if every single subject was the same age. same gender.... heck if they are all identical twins.

Comment: finish this sentence: "if everyone were the same age and gender, then  regardless of the results, i would have more confidence that it had to do with .... ?"

Comment: I think this is a valid question? Why the harsh comments? Choosing your population sample is not arbitrary. Basically the question can be re phrased as 'does emotional Stroop test results depend on age?" seems a valid topic to me.